# Android: Programmatic Phone Call Ends Immediately

Tags: android

I've been experiencing a strange problem recently in working with the ADK regarding phone calls. My goal is to trigger a phone call whenever a button is pressed on the demo shield. When I execute the following code, the phone dialer app comes up when the button is pressed (showing the number I wanted to call), however, it doesn't execute the call, only displaying the message "Call Ended".

Here's the code I've been using:

```
String url = "tel:1234567890";
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
DemoKitPhone.this.startActivity(in);
```

I've been trying to tackle this for days (putting this piece of code in runOnUiThread, BroadcastReceivers, etc. to no avail), so any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Yes, I have included the permission android.permission.CALL_PHONE. Will look through Logcat soon and post details - tahnk you.

Comment: Does your manifest declare android.permission.CALL_PHONE? Is there anything else in LogCat?

Comment: @NobuGames Hid code is working does not showing any error.

Comment: It may be working for you, but the original poster obviously has a problem which may be a device-specific one or related to something completely different. Looking at LogCat is one way to narrow down the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question properly,

This is how your caller application would have made upon. Try to open the email intent and see the behavior. It may need final intervention from user to do real action.

Answer (score 0):

add below permission in your manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name=" android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

it may solve ur problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer - I have already included the permission, but it is definitely a common error, and easy to overlook :)